# Installed theme css files not loading

Tags: magento-2.0

I had downloaded a magento theme and uploaded the files into server succefully.Permission for folders are 755 and 644 for css files.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) This is the error showing in console.Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Go through step by step.

**1) Make sure your theme added in theme.js as mentioned below path.**

> \dev\tools\grunt\configs\theme.js

replace with luma to your theme name.

```
luma: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magento/luma',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

**2) run on server commnad :**

```
   php bin/mangento cache:flush
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/mangento setup:static-content:deploy.
```

Comment: shall i add less files too ..?

Answer (score 0):

1. First clear cache and index management
2. logout and then login.